# Django log to file by date or hour

Tags: django

I know django can log to one file, but I want know how to print to different files in diff times. File name like `20150101.log` `20150102.log`.

Two questions:

1. Can I implement this by `LOGGING->filename` config ?
2. if Q1 can't, How can I dynamic change `handlers` ?

---

In other words, **How can I make django split file not by filesize but by datetime.**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**TimedRotatingFileHandler**

To log to different files based on the date or time you can use the [logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler) class.

The `TimedRotatingFileHandler` logs all messages to a file with a name that you specify. After the designated interval has elapsed it will rotate the current file to a file with the given name with the date and time appended to it.

If your filename is `myproject.log` then at the end of each interval it will rotate that file to be `myproject.log.2015-01-01` and then continue logging current messages to `myproject.log`.

Unfortunately, this class does not behave quite like you might expect. Rather than rotating based on the actual date and time, it rotates based on the time interval.

If your chosen interval is 1 day and you happen to start Django running at noon on January 1st it will not rotate at midnight and put all messages from January 1st into a file named `myproject.log.2015-01-01`. Rather, it will rotate at noon on January 2nd which is 1 day after you started. It will rotate all messages to a file named `myproject.log.2015-01-02`. So this file will contain messages from both January 1st and 2nd.

If you wish for the class to behave based on actual time it would be fairly trivial to override the class and specifically override the method called `shouldRollover`.

At least the class will give you daily intervals so you can quickly find the log files that you need. You will only have to look in two files.

To set it up in Django do the following:

```
LOGGING = { 
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },  
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'myproject.log',
            'when': 'D', # this specifies the interval
            'interval': 1, # defaults to 1, only necessary for other values 
            'backupCount': 10, # how many backup file to keep, 10 days
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },

    },  
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'),
        },
        '': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'),
        }
    },  
}
```

Comment: In newer versions of Python you can specify 'midnight' as the 'when' and it will rollover as expected

Comment: @Noah why did you not include `            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,` in the loggers part ? I perhaps fail to understand the difference between the handlers and loggers part

Comment: @Noah `logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler` file handler is not working as expected with multi-process( web application where a request is continuous coming ). At the rotation time, it truncates the log. Please suggest which work with web applications

Answer (score 2):

The `TimedRotatingFileHandler` class, located in the `logging.handlers` module, supports rotation of disk log files at certain timed intervals.
Use the `when` to specify the type of `interval`. To view the list of possible values and get more information, visit [source link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler).

Add the following to `settings.py`

```
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "formatters": {
        "verbose": {
            "format": "{levelname} {asctime} [{name}:{lineno}] {message}",  # other options: {module} {process:d} {thread:d}
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S",
            "style": "{",
        },
        "simple": {
            "format": "{levelname} {message}",
            "style": "{",
        },
    },
    "handlers": {
        "file": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "class": "logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler",
            "formatter": "verbose",
            "filename": "myproject.log",
            "when": "midnight",  # specify the type of interval
            "interval": 1,
            "backupCount": 5,  # number of backup files to keep
            "encoding": None,
            "delay": False,
            "utc": False,
            "atTime": None,
            "errors": None,
        },
        "console": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "simple",
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "django": {
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "propagate": True,
        },
        "": {
            "handlers": ["file"],
            "level": "INFO",
        },
    },
}
```

Define `logger` in the file you want to log as below:

```
import logging    
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Then use this line of code to log:

```
logger.info("logging message")
```

**Important notes**:

- The system will save old log files by appending extensions to the filename. The extensions are date-and-time based (example: myproject.log  --> myporject.log.2022-07-12)
- If the `utc` argument is true, times in UTC will be used; otherwise local time is used.
- If `atTime` is not None, it must be a `datetime.time` instance which specifies the time of day when rollover occurs, for the cases where rollover is set to happen “at midnight” or “on a particular weekday”.
- If `errors` is specified, it’s used to determine how encoding errors are handled.